# .DrawToBitmap Saved Image Wont Open In IE Browser

Tags: vb.net

The code below saves a populated form as a .JPG image. However, it needs to be able to be opened in IE browser. Any other .JPG image not generated by the code opens and if I change the code to save as a .png it also opens in IE browser. Do I need to do anything special for .JPG/ .JPEG?

Code:

```
Private Sub btnImage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnImage.Click
    Dim dialog As New FolderBrowserDialog()
    dialog.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop
    dialog.SelectedPath = ""
    dialog.Description = "Select Save Location"
    If dialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Savepath = dialog.SelectedPath
        SaveName = txtPN.Text
        If Not SaveName = "" Then

            Using bm As New Bitmap(HUD.pnlMain.Width, HUD.pnlMain.Height, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555)

                HUD.pnlMain.DrawToBitmap(bm, New Rectangle(0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height))

                bm.Save(Savepath & "\" & SaveName & ".JPG") '.PNG

            End Using
            MsgBox("Image was saved as " & SaveName & " at " & Savepath)
        Else

            Exit Sub
        End If

        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

I get this:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried [passing the format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Image_Save_System_String_System_Drawing_Imaging_ImageFormat_)? Can you open this image with an other software?

Comment: `System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg` Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try [passing the format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Image_Save_System_String_System_Drawing_Imaging_ImageFormat_).

```
bm.Save(Savepath & "\" & SaveName & ".JPG", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

Also, you could use the [Path class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) to create the full path of the file.